# Can Jaunter’s Hop or Jaunter's Strike be used as part of Sneak Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, rogue, sneak-attack, teleportation

Can [Jaunter’s Hop](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/rite-publishing-rogue-talents/jaunter-s-hop/) or [Jaunter's Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/rite-publishing-rogue-talents/jaunter-s-strike/) be used as part of Sneak Attack?

Jaunter's Hop assumes you got [Dimensional Agility](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-agility/) feat. If so, how can this work in the middle combat? I can see this as part of an ambush or during a surprise round, but I'd like to know if you do this in the heat of combat and how to pull off what Night Crawler does in the Comics, Cartoons, & Movies.

Answer (score 1):

It would be cool and thematic for sudden teleportation, as offered by either of these options, to enable sneak attack in some fashion. But unless one takes the [Dimensional Savant](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/dimensional-savant/) feat, nothing about teleporting actually accomplishes that.

However, these options don’t *prevent* sneak attack, either. If you would trigger sneak attack against the target from where you choose to teleport too, then you still do with either of these options. So teleport into a flanking position, or next to a target denied its Dex to AC, and you will get sneak attack. Which is really the same thing as you are doing with Dimensional Savant, only you are flanking with yourself.

Comment: Personally, I consider Jaunter’s Strike to be something of a trap—one standard action isn’t really going to be worth much of anything to a rogue, who really needs a full-attack to apply sneak attack enough times to be relevant. That option is far better for, say, an eldritch scoundrel, who can cast a spell as a standard action.

Comment: Well teach you can add an additional melee attack if you have the Flash Attack Feat.

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver At the cost of four feats, you can get half the attacks you should? And it won’t scale? Oh joy.

Comment: I do apologize if last comment sounds condescending. I mean to type "Well, tech" as in technically and wound up as teach, auto-correct to blame as typed from a tablet. If do somehow get the feat chain to get Dimensional Savant, I'd burn through by pool teleport motes per day. Anyways I do like the them of the teleporting Rogue and I do wonder how to make good use of these Jaunter a Talents.